# Calculating in an optimized way pow(x,y) for 0<=x<=1 and 1<y<2 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, math, optimization

For a project of mine, I am required to do a very fast computation of `pow(x,y)`. Hopefully, it is kinda restricted to a precise domain, but it need to be memory efficient enough too, if it is not fast enough.

Like I said, it is in a short scope of x between 0 and 1, and y between 1 and 2. Therefore, it has to be precise enough on the whole scope to have even a slight diminution when called recursively (and not to stall on a number)

If you guys have run into such a thing or have suggestion...

Comment: @Mehrdad edited

Comment: In what way is `exp(y*log(x))` too slow? -- What precision do you consider as sufficient? -- Try `x^y = x*(1+(x-1))^(y-1) = x*(1+(y-1)*(x-1)+(y-1)*(y-2)/2*(x-1)^2 + O(x-1)^3` as approximation.

Comment: Have you considered trying a lookup table?

Comment: I would be surprised if one were to come up with something better than the native implementation of `pow()` in the C++ library, which will likely use native FPU instructions to do the calculations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6475373/541686

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : You will be surprised if you look at the actual source of a libc implementation of pow like http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~cop4600/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source.cgi/lib/math/pow.c or https://github.com/evanphx/ulysses-libc/blob/master/src/math/pow.c .

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Problem with native pow(x,y) is that it is for y as an integer if I remember well

Comment: No, pow(x,y) is for floating point arguments both. Which leads to common questions when people expect it to work like a pure integer version.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik : What I meant to say was that it depends on what quality you address with "better". The usual implementation strive for the most exact results, so one can gain some speed by sacrificing some bits of accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `pow(x,y)` by

```
exp(y*log(x))
```

This is also sometimes the C library implementation but gives slightly distorted results for many integer inputs. Thus the `pow(x,y)` implementation usually has an overhead to catch trivial powers with exponents 0 and 1, integer powers, and does some other transformations to get the most precise result. Cutting out this overhead may be already a sufficient speed-up.

Comment: Do you think optimizing log with a lookup table could bring some more benefits since x as a defined range ? BTW thats the kind of answers i wanted

Comment: That completely depends on the processor and has to be tested. `exp(y*log(x))` requires to load two arguments on the FPU stack, do two FPU internal operations and store the result. A lookup table requires coordination of FPU, CPU and processor cache, which seems to be more complexity. But this is for standard PC architecture. On microprocessors other limitations may lead to other preferences.

Comment: In my experience, the replacement suggested here typically increases performance of the exponentiation by a factor of two with modern math libraries (probably less so with old libraries targeting x87 FPUs).

Comment: Don't STD log and exp have overhead too btw ?

Comment: One would have to compile a small program to asm to check on this, but I think that if there is a FPU command, it will be used, the only overhead being stack operations and wait cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Over such a bounded interval for both `x` & `p` the most optimal method is to run two optimized approximations of `exp2()` and `log2()`. Since the error from the `exp2()` minimax polynomial will compound exponentially but the input is always `p*log2(x) ≤ 0` for `0 < x ≤ 1` the error will be well behaved. Note: at `x = 0, log2(0) = -∞`. Below is the sample code for a `powf()` routine and the error plots of both multiple powers `1 ≤ p ≤ 2` and multiple order minimax approximations for both `log2()` and `exp2` that hopefully satisfy your absolute error tolerance.

[image]

```
float aPowf(float x, float p){
    union { float f; uint32_t u; } L2x, e2e;
    float pL2, pL2r, pL2i, E2;

    if(x == 0)  return(0.0f);

    /* Calculate log2(x) Approximation */
    L2x.f = x;
    pL2 = (uint8_t)(L2x.u >> 23) - 127;                 // log2(m*2^e) = log2(m) + e
    L2x.u = (L2x.u & ~(0xFF << 23)) | (0x7F << 23);

    // Approximate log2(x) over 1 <= x < 2, use fma() fused multiply accumulate function for efficient evaluation
    // pL2 += -0xf.4fb9dp-4 + L2x.f;    // 4.303568e-2
    // pL2 += -0x1.acc4cap0 + L2x.f *  (0x2.065084p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x5.847fe8p-4));  // 4.9397e-3
    // pL2 += -0x2.2753ccp0 + L2x.f *  (0x3.0c426p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x1.0d47dap0 + L2x.f *  0x2.88306cp-4));   // 6.3717e-4
    pL2 += -0x2.834a9p0 + L2x.f *  (0x4.11f1d8p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x2.1ee4fcp0 + L2x.f *  (0xa.52841p-4 + L2x.f *  (-0x1.4e4cf6p-4)))); // 8.761e-5
    // pL2 += -0x2.cce408p0 + L2x.f *  (0x5.177808p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x3.8cfd5cp0 + L2x.f *  (0x1.a19084p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x6.aa30dp-4 + L2x.f *  0xb.7cb75p-8))));  // 1.2542058e-5
    // pL2 += -0x3.0a3514p0 + L2x.f *  (0x6.1cbb88p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x5.5737a8p0 + L2x.f *  (0x3.490a04p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x1.442ae8p0 + L2x.f *  (0x4.66497p-4 + L2x.f *  (-0x6.925fe8p-8))))));    // 1.8533e-6
    // pL2 += -0x3.3eb71cp0 + L2x.f *  (0x7.2194ep0 + L2x.f *  (-0x7.7cf968p0 + L2x.f *  (0x5.c642f8p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x2.faeb44p0 + L2x.f *  (0xf.9e012p-4 + L2x.f *  (-0x2.ef86f8p-4 + L2x.f *  0x3.dc524p-8)))))); // 2.831e-7
    // pL2 += -0x3.6c382p0 + L2x.f *  (0x8.23b47p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x9.f803dp0 + L2x.f *  (0x9.3b4f3p0 + L2x.f *  (-0x5.f739ep0 + L2x.f *  (0x2.9cb704p0 + L2x.f *  (-0xb.d395dp-4 + L2x.f *  (0x1.f3e2p-4 + L2x.f *  (-0x2.49964p-8))))))));  // 4.7028674e-8

    pL2 *= p;
//  if(pL2 <= -128)     return(0.0f);

    /* Calculate exp2(p*log2(x)) */
    pL2i = floorf(pL2);
    pL2r = pL2 - pL2i;
    e2e.u = ((int)pL2i + 127) << 23;

    // Approximate exp2(x) over 0 <= x < 1, use fma() fused multiply accumulate function for efficient evaluation.
    // E2 = 0xf.4fb9dp-4 + pL2r;    // 4.303568e-2
    // E2 = 0x1.00a246p0 + pL2r * (0xa.6aafdp-4 + pL2r * 0x5.81078p-4); // 2.4761e-3
    // E2 = 0xf.ff8fcp-4 + pL2r * (0xb.24b0ap-4 + pL2r * (0x3.96e39cp-4 + pL2r * 0x1.446bc8p-4));   // 1.0705e-4
    E2 = 0x1.00003ep0 + pL2r * (0xb.1663cp-4 + pL2r * (0x3.ddbffp-4 + pL2r * (0xd.3b9afp-8 + pL2r * 0x3.81ade8p-8)));   // 3.706393e-6
    // E2 = 0xf.ffffep-4 + pL2r * (0xb.1729bp-4 + pL2r * (0x3.d79b5cp-4 + pL2r * (0xe.4d721p-8 + pL2r * (0x2.49e21p-8 + pL2r * 0x7.c5b598p-12))));  // 1.192e-7
    // E2 = 0x1.p0 + pL2r * (0xb.17215p-4 + pL2r * (0x3.d7fb5p-4 + pL2r * (0xe.34192p-8 + pL2r * (0x2.7a7828p-8 + pL2r * (0x5.15bd08p-12 + pL2r * 0xe.48db2p-16)))));   // 2.9105833e-9
    // E2 = 0x1.p0 + pL2r * (0xb.17218p-4 + pL2r * (0x3.d7f7acp-4 + pL2r * (0xe.35916p-8 + pL2r * (0x2.761acp-8 + pL2r * (0x5.7e9f9p-12 + pL2r * (0x9.70c6ap-16 + pL2r * 0x1.666008p-16))))));  // 8.10693e-11
    // E2 = 0x1.p0 + pL2r * (0xb.17218p-4 + pL2r * (0x3.d7f7b8p-4 + pL2r * (0xe.35874p-8 + pL2r * (0x2.764dccp-8 + pL2r * (0x5.76b95p-12 + pL2r * (0xa.15ca6p-16 + pL2r * (0xf.94e0dp-20 + pL2r * 0x1.cc690cp-20)))))));    // 3.9714478e-11

    return(E2 * e2e.f);
}
```

Once the appropriate minimax approximation is chosen make sure to implement the horner polynomial evaluation with fused multiply accumulate operations fma() [which are single cycle instruction].

Increasing the accuracy further can be done by introducing a LUT for a type of range reduction for increased accuracy of the logarithm function.