# Four times four oversampling performance

Tags: c++, optimization, renderer, image-scaling, oversampling

In the process of making a rendering engine that fundamentally relies on four times four oversampling, I ran into the performance of the downscaling itself.

```
#include <stdint.h>

    const int_fast32_t sRGBtolinear[256] = {0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 99, 119, 139, 159, 179, 199, 219, 241, 264, 288, 313, 340, 367, 396, 427, 458, 491, 526, 562, 599, 637, 677, 718, 761, 805, 851, 898, 947, 997, 1048, 1101, 1156, 1212, 1270, 1330, 1391, 1453, 1517, 1583, 1651, 1720, 1791, 1863, 1937, 2013, 2090, 2170, 2250, 2333, 2418, 2504, 2592, 2681, 2773, 2866, 2961, 3058, 3157, 3258, 3360, 3464, 3570, 3678, 3788, 3900, 4014, 4129, 4247, 4366, 4488, 4611, 4736, 4864, 4993, 5124, 5257, 5392, 5530, 5669, 5810, 5953, 6099, 6246, 6395, 6547, 6701, 6856, 7014, 7174, 7336, 7500, 7666, 7834, 8004, 8177, 8352, 8529, 8708, 8889, 9072, 9258, 9446, 9636, 9828, 10022, 10219, 10418, 10619, 10822, 11028, 11236, 11446, 11658, 11873, 12090, 12309, 12531, 12754, 12981, 13209, 13440, 13673, 13909, 14147, 14387, 14629, 14874, 15122, 15372, 15624, 15878, 16135, 16394, 16656, 16920, 17187, 17456, 17727, 18001, 18278, 18556, 18838, 19121, 19408, 19696, 19988, 20281, 20578, 20876, 21178, 21481, 21788, 22096, 22408, 22722, 23038, 23357, 23679, 24003, 24329, 24659, 24991, 25325, 25662, 26002, 26344, 26689, 27036, 27387, 27739, 28095, 28453, 28813, 29177, 29543, 29911, 30283, 30657, 31033, 31413, 31795, 32180, 32567, 32957, 33350, 33746, 34144, 34545, 34949, 35355, 35765, 36177, 36591, 37009, 37429, 37852, 38278, 38707, 39138, 39572, 40009, 40449, 40892, 41337, 41786, 42237, 42691, 43147, 43607, 44069, 44534, 45003, 45474, 45947, 46424, 46904, 47386, 47871, 48360, 48851, 49345, 49842, 50342, 50844, 51350, 51859, 52370, 52884, 53402, 53922, 54445, 54972, 55501, 56033, 56568, 57106, 57647, 58191, 58738, 59288, 59841, 60397, 60956, 61518, 62083, 62651, 63222, 63796, 64373, 64953, 65536};
    const int_fast32_t lineartosRGBthr[256] = {0, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130, 150, 170, 189, 209, 230, 253, 276, 301, 327, 354, 382, 412, 443, 475, 509, 544, 580, 618, 657, 698, 740, 783, 828, 875, 923, 972, 1023, 1075, 1129, 1185, 1242, 1300, 1360, 1422, 1486, 1551, 1617, 1685, 1755, 1827, 1900, 1975, 2052, 2130, 2210, 2292, 2376, 2461, 2548, 2637, 2727, 2820, 2914, 3010, 3108, 3208, 3309, 3412, 3518, 3625, 3734, 3844, 3957, 4072, 4188, 4307, 4427, 4550, 4674, 4800, 4929, 5059, 5191, 5325, 5461, 5600, 5740, 5882, 6026, 6172, 6321, 6471, 6624, 6779, 6935, 7094, 7255, 7418, 7583, 7750, 7920, 8091, 8265, 8440, 8618, 8798, 8981, 9165, 9352, 9541, 9732, 9925, 10121, 10318, 10518, 10721, 10925, 11132, 11341, 11552, 11766, 11981, 12200, 12420, 12643, 12868, 13095, 13325, 13557, 13791, 14028, 14267, 14508, 14752, 14998, 15247, 15498, 15751, 16007, 16265, 16525, 16788, 17054, 17322, 17592, 17864, 18140, 18417, 18697, 18980, 19265, 19552, 19842, 20135, 20430, 20727, 21027, 21330, 21635, 21942, 22252, 22565, 22880, 23198, 23518, 23841, 24166, 24494, 24825, 25158, 25494, 25832, 26173, 26517, 26863, 27212, 27563, 27917, 28274, 28633, 28995, 29360, 29727, 30097, 30470, 30845, 31223, 31604, 31987, 32373, 32762, 33154, 33548, 33945, 34345, 34747, 35152, 35560, 35971, 36384, 36800, 37219, 37641, 38065, 38493, 38923, 39355, 39791, 40229, 40671, 41115, 41562, 42011, 42464, 42919, 43377, 43838, 44302, 44769, 45238, 45711, 46186, 46664, 47145, 47629, 48116, 48605, 49098, 49593, 50092, 50593, 51097, 51604, 52114, 52627, 53143, 53662, 54184, 54709, 55236, 55767, 56300, 56837, 57377, 57919, 58465, 59013, 59564, 60119, 60676, 61237, 61800, 62367, 62936, 63509, 64084, 64663, 65245};

 uint_least8_t lineartosRGB(int32_t value){
    uint_least8_t a = 0;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+128] <= value) a+=128;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+ 64] <= value) a+= 64;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+ 32] <= value) a+= 32;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+ 16] <= value) a+= 16;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+  8] <= value) a+=  8;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+  4] <= value) a+=  4;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+  2] <= value) a+=  2;
    if(lineartosRGBthr[a+  1] <= value) a+=  1;
    return a;
 }

 uint32_t RGBavg16(const uint32_t* pixel){
    int_fast32_t red = 0;
    int_fast32_t green = 0;
    int_fast32_t blue = 0;
    for(int_fast16_t i=0; i<16; i++){
        red   += sRGBtolinear[(pixel[i]>>16)&0xFF];
        green += sRGBtolinear[(pixel[i]>> 8)&0xFF];
        blue  += sRGBtolinear[(pixel[i]    )&0xFF];
    }
    return lineartosRGB((red+8)>>4)*65536+lineartosRGB((green+8)>>4)*256+lineartosRGB((blue+8)>>4)*1;
 }

void fourtimesfouroversampling(int* stagesize, uint32_t* pixels, int pixelsscanlineoffset, uint32_t* oversampled, int oversampledscanlineoffset){
        for(int i=0; i<stagesize[1]; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<stagesize[0]; j++){
            uint32_t pixel[16];
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++){
                for(int l=0; l<4; l++){
                    pixel[k*4+l] = oversampled[i*4*oversampledscanlineoffset+j*4+l+k*oversampledscanlineoffset];
                }
            }
            pixels[i*pixelsscanlineoffset+j] = RGBavg16(pixel);
        }
    }
}
```

Four times four oversampling is a way to achieve anti-aliasing by rendering the exact same way one would do with no anti-aliasing or smoothing methods (bilevel outline rendering, nearest neighbor graphics, etc.) but on a four times four times larger oversampled stage. Then a box filter is used to downscale each pixel by taking the linear average of each sixteen pixel square. The sRGB/linear conversions are required because the sRGB values cannot directly be averaged as they are not a linear scale.

To test performance, use the following main after the previous code, which draws random oversampled pixels and downscales them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
    const int width = 640;
    const int height = 480;
    int stagesize[2] = {width, height};
    uint32_t pixels[width*height];
    uint32_t oversampled[width*4*height*4];
int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<width*4*height*4; i++) oversampled[i]=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<60; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<4096; j++){
            oversampled[rand()%(height*4)*(width*4)+rand()%(width*4)] = rand();
        }
        fourtimesfouroversampling(stagesize, pixels, width, oversampled, width*4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It ends up being on average about 3.731 seconds when -O3 compiled. As the code is unable to render the 60 frames in a second, it is unable to sustain 60fps rendering, and the 60fps program using this renderer would not run at the full speed. What should be done to make the four times four oversampling sustain the 60fps?

Comment: Parallelize and vectorize it. Or better yet, use GPU acceleration.

Comment: But how would I do that? (Minimum requirements: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this is much slower than necessary. First though, how are you measuring the speed? Your `main()` looks like it is only running for 60 frames, that is probably not enough to get an accuracte measurement once you have optimized `fourtimesfouroversampling()`. You also want to measure only the time spent in `fourtimesfouroversampling()`, and not in the setup code, not the loop that fills `oversampled[]` with random values, not any time the caches have to warm up and so on.

The binary search you do in `lineartosRGB()` is probably going to be very slow. If the CPU supports conditional move instructions, then it is not too bad, but you still have 7 indirect loads, and since the next load depends on the value previously loaded, there is no way to pipeline this efficiently. It is probably faster to use a precalculated 65545 entry lookup table.

Another possibility is to avoid the lookup tables, and use floating point math instead. That sounds crazy, but the advantage is that you can process multiple pixels in one go with SSE instructions. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475373/optimizations-for-pow-with-const-non-integer-exponent) for how to optimize `pow()`.

Also, I would avoid the temporary array `pixel[16]`, and just merge `RGBavg16()` with `fourtimesfouroversampling()`.

See [this example on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaIAEwAGUqvQAZPLUwA5PQCNMxQQAdU0wktqad%2Bo6bunop0Vjb2uk4unDJymAreDATMxAS%2BegYmsfIhtEkpBGF2js6C0smp6f5Z5QVFEVFcAJQyqNrEyBwA5ACkhgDM1sg6WADUPf3q5fj0AHQIE9g9xgCCyyuYAB4EzrSjaLTlo9YEYlTM5f2GYgSj0gBKAOIAQkSs1pgpPQCsz4bfADYfgARCbPdZbHbEPYHI4nM4XAhXG6jd42AoeJ6vBDEH7PAHfb7cb4gsHrda1RTIUbaeHsREADhRaM%2BqUxLwgJ2RtwAbmxtJgmuMAOzg1ajCWjYiYAjtPYsjEPF4EHF4vk6TCk/pitbC0GrdY81B4dCjGjtRS6TDSc3EVA85zSZi6Vxo4Cc%2BgAKjuyWA1rwAC9MKQaVzrgRva48Js5NIQydRlGY6xpNIWLQWagqFRZAQQ7T6NzvfbHc7XZh0PH6KMS8QnS72Og0yJM9nc00eqL1pKzSQPbc8BNgcYwccJlNff6g3jOFrnmPDODFx2u%2BKe5KaMR%2B6M%2BEOR9qd%2BPan7PNPfiPvqCD7vF31niudeun8d6AjLuGpRXxv1gaMGWS12fSV4XOd8UWAaVVG/X9/21bsgOA19QKRD8HA1aC/wAtZAIQzdtwAaz3UdCMmbhiLvO8hU7R8EKfPCE1YIiD0Y0jR0Y29lxFGjaKA2FbgLFCUSTOQMNrety3QPE8E9bhPTEstG2bDMPizHMZTvPgZLvdjnnwuSHTrBSKyU1s1IIOdyRwnj12lU0JQon87ixN4Pi%2BX4IGEliln6bBOABDtDABYxNgAMRCiyrOsyUIMwKCHN/JVXi0VzcXczzFkWP8AqC0LwsvLCoufNCBXs29HMSlz0VS54POjETJWy4KwoilZCvsvV4Nozt9Vatqe06hDPOkKTPSGkyVLbdTF13S8MIVNlEogWyMp87gmk9Alvn6AERXUVEUqIRaYtUFbsDWz1/h2zs9vmw6sQgYrNR8xY1oK59uoGj6DT1LoWlYEAum%2BLpSAMLpjGB1AAb26Q2g6TBxgGThgYIAHwaaFp8JAb5hVmAEGQBYUGT84wAE5OBJokYn%2BrpuGB0HwdISGumB6QQFMFGwd%2B0g4FgJA0BdPB2DICgIH5qMhZQYBpFoZhXGkBBUDzKhBahVmHtR4GHGsFIAE8AaR0h%2BategAHkMz1znSCwXQRGAdgNatvBpQSB1WctrZ4m0HYHZOOQHfeBxiF1zQsH15HiDwXQw5aGh6CYNgOB4fhBGEUQQAkMQpAD1nIBaVBXFyN2AFps0RIubZVUZy5SZAFh/GXFAdKuTeQlm4gSZQIHMKoDBicx6hKaJSCCLw6B7twPFH2gB8iUoYlkHJEgqNItAyMp29yfJUhnxp5%2BX8e97qD4GjnloYfaTpmiEAGgZBh2mc2fGi4BbhRmAZBqQgAhiG0Wh8KFCAuBCAkARv0GIoxNACyFqAzgQp1DIw1ujUgmNuCGFmGAq4nAGT9BJsYBkxhiQk2vjTYGUdODGFMPTCGAMWZs1IBzNGf0AaGDpvfGh9DEEtAMp4ZQ3AgA%3D%3D%3D) for some of the changes mentioned above, except for the floating point math. Regardless of which compiler is used, they all unroll the inner two loops. Each pixel is processed separately, since the table lookups unfortunately cannot be done in parallel using SSE instructions.

Comment: "The successive approximation you do in lineartosRGB()" is a binary search used to find the first value equal or greater than the threshold. The conditional branching is the way binary search functions.
Why specifically, 65545? Is there something I missed that makes it possible to have the 8 linear values from 65537 to 65544?

Comment: The binary search you do is similar to what a [successive approximation ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive-approximation_ADC) does. Ah, it's 65537 indeed, I see now the `+ 8` is followed by a `>> 4`.

Comment: The addition of 8 before bitshifting is equivalent to adding 0.5 before taking the floor. It ensures the average is rounded to the nearest.