# Any trick to compute faster Math.pow(10, (0.1x+1.5))?

Tags: performance, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, compiler-optimization

my Java algorithm is spending 30% of its time calculating the expression `Math.pow(10, (0.1x+1.5))` for many different x values (I cannot know these x's beforehand). Is there any way/trick to lower this bottleneck?

Comment: That's `pow(a, x) * b` where `a = pow(10, 0.1)` and `b = 10 * sqrt(10)` which may be a bit faster though not by much.

Comment: What kind of algorithm? There may be special opportunities that arise thanks to some special context in which that power appears

Comment: [Optimizations for pow() with const non-integer exponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475373/995714)

Comment: `pow` and `exp` can be vectorized and be computed faster if you know that `x` is a normalized finite number (so not `NaN` or `Inf` or even `-0`) assuming the machine use a standard IEEE-754 representation for floating-point numbers. Such kind of trick is not portable (and not well suited to Java).

Comment: I'm also curious to know what you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

An other option is:

```
31.6227766017 * Math.exp(0.23025850929 * x)
```

This is likely faster, because `exp` is simpler than `pow`, but I did not test how big the difference (if any) is.

Comment: those numbers are exactly 10^1.5 and 0.1*ln(10)